# How to use clock to run program on time?

Tags: mp3, clock, scheduled

For example:

I want to set when 6:00 am it plays 1.mp3 (if 2.mp3 is playing then close 2.mp3).

When 18:00 it plays 2.mp3 to replace 1.mp3 (replace means close 1.mp3 and play 2.mp3).

Everyday was the above sequence.

How to do it?

Comment: Check out `man crontab`

Comment: [Possible duplicate](http://askubuntu.com/questions/8891)

Comment: I try to edit crontab's conf: 51 22 * * * /home/sam/mp3.sh   and I restart cron service by 'sudo service cron restart'.Why it also couldn't run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alarm Clock (`alarm-clock-applet`) in the Ubuntu Software Center provides an easy way to execute certain commands at certain times on a repeating schedule.

I imagine your commands executed at each alarm would look something like this:
`banshee --hide --stop; banshee --hide --play <Your .mp3 filename and path here>`