# Scheduling StartUp and ShutDown

Tags: power-management, shutdown, schedule

I use Torrents often, so I need to know how to make my computer start up and shut down automatically, Wi-Fi is switched on at six in the morning in my hotel and switched off at two AM. (I am able to schedule torrents, that's not a problem), I don't want my computer always plugged in to a power supply.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

For a one-time shutdown you can use

```
shutdown -h 02:00
```

To schedule it you can use [cron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron). There are some GUIs for it like **[gnome-schedule](http://gnome-schedule.sourceforge.net/)**.

But to start machine on schedule you have to look at BIOS/UEFI settings.

**Update**: check the answers about **MythTV** and **Wake on Plan** below to schedule startup.

Comment: This question may be useful: [How do I schedule waking up from hibernation?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/8845/how-do-i-schedule-waking-up-from-hibernation)

Answer (score 13):

**MythTV** is able to shut down computer when it's no longer in use and wake it up a few minutes before the next recording starts. It does it by using ACPI functions to set wakeup time before shutting down. There is an [extensive howto](http://www.mythtv.org/wiki/ACPI_Wakeup#Using_.2Fsys.2Fclass.2Frtc.2Frtc0.2Fwakealarm) on configuring this, which basically boils down to:

First verify that your Linux kernel is 2.6.22 or newer and the HWclock update function has been disabled as described above.

Simple test to wake the machine 5 minutes from now

```
sudo sh -c "echo 0 > /sys/class/rtc/rtc0/wakealarm"
sudo sh -c "echo `date '+%s' -d '+ 5 minutes'` > /sys/class/rtc/rtc0/wakealarm"
cat /sys/class/rtc/rtc0/wakealarm
```

Check

```
cat /proc/driver/rtc
```

This should return a list of parameters. Check the "alrm_time" is 5 minutes into the future and the "alrm_date" is today.

Shutdown your computer and see if it comes back up in ~5 min.

```
sudo shutdown -h now
```

(in Ubuntu 10.4 "sudo shutdown -P now" (-h may cause system to restart))

Of course, if you always need to shut the computer down at the same time and wake it up at the same time, you can just configure wake-up time in bios (if there's such an option) and schedule a shutdown right from init scripts

Comment: Great, didn't know about it. Should alrm_pending be 'yes' if alarm is set?

Comment: On my machine alarm_pending is "no" even after I set the wake-up time using the script above. The machine wakes up perfectly though so I think this parameter means something else

Answer (score 13):

Use a cronjob to auto sleep and auto resume. The command below will put the the computer to sleep at 02.00 AM and start the machine 4 hours later (14400 seconds)

```
00 2 * * * root /usr/sbin/rtcwake -m off -s 14400
```

Comment: This seems like the simplest solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

I've written an application to schedule startup, it's called **Wake on Plan**.

It's not available in the official repository yet ([review](https://myapps.developer.ubuntu.com/dev/apps/1188/) pending) but you can start using it from PPA:

https://launchpad.net/~xintx-ua/+archive/wakeonplan

#### 2014-2015 Update:

I've created the [QML version](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~xintx-ua/wakeonplan/wakeonplan/files/head:/wakeonplan-qml/) with Ubuntu SDK using phone as a target and hoping for easy porting to desktop over a year ago. But click packages were never ready for use on desktop and now I'm waiting until snappy packages will be. Please notify me when they are. Right now even `snappy list -uv` crashed on my 15.04x64 installation and it doesn't look ready at all. Or you can try building a deb packages yourself, I'll try to help as much as I can.

Comment: I've tried it (January 18th, 2013) and it works well under 12.10 — though there is no "Quantal" package. Is it under active development?

Comment: Thanks for the info :) Not really active as it's still wasn't approved due to one empty folder in the package that I can't find how to get rid of, check here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/221701

Comment: And Quickly 12.08.x intended for usage under 12.10 breaks a lot, so I first wanted to finish the 12.04 version.

Comment: Does this still work? If so, could you build packages for more recent Ubuntu versions please? :)

Comment: Short: ASAP. Long: Thanks for the question, I'm planning to do it but a little bit overwhelmed with work currently.

Comment: updated the body

Answer (score 1):

I'm using an older Ubuntu 10.04.4 LTS system, and I have had some success with the [rtcwake](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man8/rtcwake.8.html) command.  Use it like this on the command line:

```
# wake the system in 1 Hour:
sudo rtcwake -s 3600 -m disk
```

The `-m disk` option should put it in a low-power state, and depending on hardware support (i.e.: your own computer),  you might even be able to successfully use `-m off` to fully power off.

Also, you can put the above into the [/etc/crontab](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto) to schedule it automatically every day.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `shutdown` command to schedule a shutdown. To shutdown at 2 AM you can use the following command:

```
sudo shutdown -h 2:00
```

You will need to run this command in terminal and leave the terminal open.

Regarding startup, I dont think that it is possible for Ubuntu or any app running on it to switch on a computer. You will need hardware assistance for this for example you can use **Wake on Lan**.

Comment: Regarding startup - you're correct in a very narrow technical sense (because Ubuntu is not running when a computer is down), but with a bit of trickery it *is* possible to schedule a wakeup from a program/script. :)

Comment: I don't think you need to keep the terminal open.  You can stop the job with `ctrl-z` and then use `bg` to background it.  Log out, log in and `ps ax | grep shutdown` should show that it's still running.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest this command in your cron:

```
dbus-send --system --print-reply --dest=org.freedesktop.UPower /org/freedesktop/UPower org.freedesktop.UPower.Suspend
```

This does not need root.