# need help for alarm

Tags: clock

recently i have switched to ubuntu from windows just because i like to explorer new areas but sticked here at ubuntu but there is a problem that i am a heavy sleeper and need alarm that wakes me in morning for my uni i have tried my alarms in ubuntu but couldnt find anyone that wakes my computer from sleepmode or from hibernation is there any software that does that thing 
need help please

Comment: An advice please switch off your pc while sleeping ,buy a separate alarm clock or use alarm feature in your mobile phone

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind some scripting you can check [my answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/83706/14564) to a similar question here.

UPDATE: Actually, searching Ubuntu repositories for "wake" found the following application:

**wakeup**

> This package has a complete **graphical front end** with which a user can
>   **set an alarm to wake the computer** - from poweroff if possible - and
>   read a user-defined text. This text can grab relevant information
>   (date, time, weather, Evolution schedule and tasks, news from an rss
>   feed, number of new email messages, etc.) and speak that as well, or
>   play music, all as defined by the user. More capabilities can be added
>   to the alarm via a complete and simple plugin system. Supports
>   multiple alarms.

Looks like exactly what you want

You can install it using

```
sudo apt-get install wakeup
```

or just via Software Center

Comment: That does not seem to work with recent Ubuntu versions anymore. [https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/quantal/wakeup/]

Answer (score 0):

**Try this link [Alarm clock pseudoberries](http://alarm-clock.pseudoberries.com/) They have a good one on this site.**

[image]
[image]

To get started, press Ctrl – Alt – T on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the commands below to install:

Enter code here:

```
sudo apt-get install alarm-clock-applet
```

*Enjoy!*

Comment: But this program is not able to wake up a hybernated/sleeping computer as far as I'm aware...

Comment: Yeah i think Sergey has a good point that you would have to input some code maybe into an API/Kernel to get that to work as i was reading your intro at the top, it looks like your new to linux. So you may have to do some reading, if your not new to it all then you should find what your looking for. :)