# What in Quickly creates an empty .../share/gnome/help/.../C/figures/ folder?

Tags: application-development, quickly, packaging

Something in packaging scripts creates an empty `figures` folder where it's not present before [this packaging](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~xintx-ua/wakeonplan/wakeonplan/files/head:/help/C/).

Where is it?

Comment: I don't use Quickly, but have you looked at your setup.py file? You could also `grep` your source dir to see where it comes from: `grep -Inr "figures" *`

Comment: I've already grepped.

Answer (score 1):

Almost any GNOME application (maybe GNOME 2) would create such folder with path:

```
/share/gnome/help/[appname]/C/figures/
```

... where [appname] is your GNOME application and folder `figures` can include various graphic files.

Cite from *GNOME 2 Development Guide*:

> *For example, if your installation prefix is /opt/gnome , you'll find the original documentation for the GNOME terminal in /opt/gnome/share/gnome/help/ terminal/C and the images for the German documentation for Gnumeric in /opt/ gnome/share/gnome/help/gnumeric/de/figures.*

Comment: But what script creates it? Or, alternatively, how can I disable it?

Comment: obviously it depends on what was hidden under wildcard [...] inside this path ... so reasonable question is: How to find APPLICATION with empty folder 'figures' in the common shared GNOME help directory? :)
looks at least strange ... that it?

Comment: just I think it isn't Quickly. Or you if you can log your Quickly, then it should to show this a bit more better. In the Quickly it can be some helpDoc generator which make it next or before of building app ...

Answer (score 0):

This folder is present in the `/usr/share/quickly/templates/ubuntu-application/project_root` folder which is what I think is copied over when you create a new project. If I remove that directory, when I create a new application with quickly, the help/C/figures directory is no longer there.

EDIT:  I goofed... didn't check your path in the title of the question. Sorry, this path isn't removed, when you delete it from the template.