# How to wake-up / suspend (or switch-off) Ubuntu 12.10 Desktop system automatically at a particular time of the day?

Tags: 12.10, power-management, suspend, gnome-power-manager

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Scheduling StartUp and ShutDown](https://askubuntu.com/questions/83685/scheduling-startup-and-shutdown)

Currently, I keep my Ubuntu 12.10 Desktop system continuously running as I have to download some data at a particular time which generally takes half an hour.

**In order to save the power (electricity)**

**Question:**: How can I wake-up my system (from suspended or switched off mode) at a particular time i.e. 2:15 AM (everyday) and and put it in a suspension mode or switched off mode at a particular time i.e. 3:15 AM (everyday) only if the keyboard or mouse activity is not detected for particular period i.e. 15 minutes.?

N.B. The system is connected with Internet with Router which has "Always On" connection.

Comment: Please see this answer for instructions and links: http://askubuntu.com/a/83706/14564