# Can I figure out why my system started? Was it due to WOL?

Tags: boot, restart

Recently my computer turned on unexpectedly. It is configured to respond to WOL (Wake-On-LAN) but at that time I didn't send any magic packet. It came on out of nowhere.

How can I figure out why it turned on? I already looked at `journalctl -b` and grepped through various logfiles below `/var/log` but couldn't find any hint.

Comment: Is your BIOS configured to boot after lost power is restored?

Comment: @user535733 Good point. I don't think so. At least I didn't change anything recently. Right now I cannot verify (because it's my office computer). I'll check tomorrow.

Comment: If it's an office computer, it's likely that your IT dept woke it to perform a Windows update, or perform a network survey.

Comment: @heynnema Also a valid point. I can check that with them but I doubt it. We are in the luxurious situation that the IT dept doesn't bother our computers if we don't ask them to.

Comment: Any chance you were experimenting with shutdown that automatically boots up at specific time?: https://askubuntu.com/questions/83685/scheduling-startup-and-shutdown?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: To find out how you shut down last, use: `journalctl -b-1`.