# How do I schedule boot ubuntu 18.04LTS?

Tags: 18.04, power-management, reboot, schedule

I have tried the WakeOnLan Application but it does not work in 18.04 LTS as provided in following solution:

1. [Scheduling StartUp and ShutDown](https://askubuntu.com/questions/83685/scheduling-startup-and-shutdown)

I have dual boot windows 10 and Ubuntu So I cannot change time settings on system.

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? Automatically boot at a certain time when the computer is currently off?

Comment: Yes,  boot at certain time when computer is off

Comment: I think that's something you do in your BIOS. The WakeOnLan is another solution in which case another computer would send network packets on the LAN which the BIOS would detect and the computer wakes up. But I never used any of these features myself.

Comment: I have tried in BIOS but there is no option of Power Management in my BIOS. and I am not having lan cable at my home which can be used to connect to WOL.

Comment: The question is not related to Ubuntu. If your BIOS doesn't have this feture, you can't do it.