# Running processes when machine is suspended

Tags: suspend

Would it be possible to run specific software processes when your machine goes into suspend mode?

Comment: This is a different question - OP wants to know if processes can actually be *run* while the computer is suspended.

Comment: I agree with @searchfgold6789 the question is NOT a duplicate of the specified program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, during suspend you won't be able to run any useful process: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sleep_mode

Your only solution would be to wake periodically to perform whatever task you're interested in and then enter suspend again when done. If you are interested in tasks like torrent clients that likely won't be feasible since they don't fall into that pattern of on-briefly-and-suspend-when-done.

[This answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/113379/suspend-and-wake-pc-at-certain-time) will be useful to figure out timed suspend and wake.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is No. When the device is suspended, all of the components are shut down except the RAM. Transmission needs things like your CPU and network card, which in turn need different things running. The best thing to do to keep processes running while the computer is not in use is to just Lock it.

Source: `man pm-action`

Answer (score 0):

No, cause something like BitTorrent will use CPU, HDD and WiFi
That means nothing can suspend.
it's like downloading a file on your mobile phone, even if you turned off the screen the battery will drain and the phone gets hot cause he didnt even suspend

Answer (score 0):

13.04 is old, and no longer supported. Consider upgrading.

You CAN run a process as your system enters hibernation (well, at each of Sleep/Wake/Suspend/Resume). read `man pm-action` or https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man8/pm-action.8.html

Comment: the question is old so the op have probably upgraded multiple times over the last 6 years.

Comment: That is correct