# Is wake up from standby possible via script or schedule?

Tags: hibernate, cron, power-management, sleep, scheduled

Is it possible to cause Ubuntu to resume from standby or sleep mode to run a scheduled task like `at` job/crontab? (hibernation seems to be ruled out in another question)

Can a script be written that:

1. standby (to cycle power to devices with buggy drivers, *for example*)
2. sleeps N seconds
3. wakes up and continues. (restarts network-manager if necessary)

This is not a "Wake-on-LAN" problem. The event is purely internal and connected via wifi only anyway.

Comment: You must be talking about this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/61708/automatically-sleep-and-wake-up-at-specific-times

Comment: Originally I read http://askubuntu.com/questions/8845/how-do-i-schedule-waking-up-from-hibernation showing I can do `sudo bash -c "echo $(date '+%s' -d 'tomorrow 6am') > /sys/class/rtc/rtc0/wakealarm"`, but your link lead to great info too.