# Shutdown a computer after long inactivity while being in Sleep mode

Tags: suspend, power-management, shutdown

I somehow discovered that Sleep mode actually takes way more energy out of Laptop's battery than usually in a complete computer Shut Down.

I would like to know how it might be possible to Wake up the computer after certain time of inactivity and Shut It Down, to save the energy for the night.

Comment: It does if you keep WIFI, BT and USB connection active. If those are disabled it will most certainly not use more energy when sleeping.

Comment: A combination of https://askubuntu.com/questions/113379/suspend-and-wake-pc-at-certain-time and https://askubuntu.com/questions/8845/how-do-i-schedule-waking-up-from-hibernation seem to do what you want.

Comment: What you want is hybrid-sleep where after being suspended for awhile the system hibernates which is to say RAM is copied to disk and the machine is shut off. All work is saved for when machine wakes from hibernation. It is similar to resuming from suspend except it takes longer. Just as that.takes longer than thawing after freeze.